# any ideas to solve it?

Tags: java, mysql, netbeans

this is the messege i recieved
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'complex.cox_Id='1'' at line 1

```
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
           Connection conn=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/optimalcms","root","123456");
                   Statement st=conn.createStatement();
                     PreparedStatement pst; 
                     Object item = RenterRevealeds_ComplexName_ComboBox.getSelectedItem();
                    int value = ((Item)item).getId(); 


            String sql="Select complex.cox_name as 'أسم المجمع',complex.cox_bld_num as 'رقم المجمع',client.clnt_name as 'أسم المسأجر',client.clnt_phone_number as 'رقم هاتف المستأجر',office.ofc_num as 'رقم المكتب',status.status_ofc_status as 'حالةالمكتب'"
                    + "from client"
                    + "INNER JOIN office ON office.ofc_Id = client.clnt_ofc_Id "
                    + "INNER JOIN complex ON complex.cox_Id = client.clnt_cox_Id"
                    + "INNER JOIN status ON status.status_Id = office.ofc_status_Id"
                    + "WHERE complex.cox_Id='"+value+"'";
            pst= conn.prepareStatement(sql);
            ResultSet rs;
            rs=pst.executeQuery();
            jTable1.setModel(DbUtils.resultSetToTableModel(rs));
           conn.close();
```

Comment: I would say that you have an error in your SQL syntax and you should check the MySQL documentation for the right syntax to use. (Printing out the query before running it should help you see what your program sends to MySQL and why it's wrong)

Comment: You do realize that string concatenation like that in an sql query leaves your program wide open for sql injection attacks?

Comment: i really have checked the query before running the program and its work

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget to add spaces between the words:

```
"INNER JOIN complex ON complex.cox_Id = client.clnt_cox_Id"
```

should have a trailing space, like:

```
"INNER JOIN complex ON complex.cox_Id = client.clnt_cox_Id "
```

And the next line as well (as well as the first and second lines).

Comment: I edited my answer (there were more places with missing spaces). Anyway, if that didn't work, try to write out the query in one line before chopping it up, and try to run it agains MySql outside your program (in the database management interface) to see if it works.